# react hooks form + MUI wrapper shows warning on ref

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I created a wrapper around MUI TextField using react hook forms:

```
import { Control, Controller, FieldValues, Path, RegisterOptions } from 'react-hook-form';

import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material/TextField';

export interface IRHFTextFieldProps<TField extends FieldValues> {
  name: Path<TField>;
  control: Control<TField>;
  rules?: Omit<RegisterOptions<TField>, 'disabled' | 'valueAsNumber' | 'valueAsDate' | 'setValueAs'> | undefined;
}

export function RHFTextField<TField extends FieldValues>({
  name,
  control,
  ...props
}: IRHFTextFieldProps<TField> & TextFieldProps) {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field, fieldState }) => {
        const { onBlur: propsOnBlur, ...propsRest } = props;
        const { ref, onBlur, ...rest } = field;
        const { error } = fieldState;
        return (
          <TextField
            {...propsRest}
            {...rest}
            helperText={error?.message}
            error={!!error}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            inputRef={ref}
            onBlur={propsOnBlur || onBlur}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I use it like this:

```
<RHFTextField
              sx={{ flex: 2 }}
              label={t('labels.name')}
              placeholder={namePlaceHolder}
              control={control}
              {...register('name', { required: t('validation.required-field') })}
              onBlur={() => trigger('name')}
            />
```

It's working fine but i'm seeing these warnings in chrome console:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref
> will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Any idea how to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend updating the `<RHFTextField />` component to use `React.forwardRef()` to pass the `ref` to the underlying `<TextField/>` component, which should address the issue about function components not receiving refs.